# Why is Slim Framework's phpErrorHandler not working?

Tags: php, reporting, slim, slim-3

I'm having trouble getting the phpErrorHandler to work. I'm using the latest version of Slim and my server is running PHP 7.1.

```
use \Slim\App as App;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new App([
    'errorHandler' => function ($c) {
        return function ($request, $response, $error) use ($c) {
            return $c['response']
                ->withStatus(500)
                ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                ->write('application error');
        };
    },
    'phpErrorHandler' => function ($c) {
        return function ($request, $response, $error) use ($c) {
            return $c['response']
                ->withStatus(500)
                ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                ->write('runtime error');
        };
    }
]);
```

When I throw an Exception from my code, the error handler is invoked and my output is "application error". However, when I throw an Error from my code or introduce syntax errors, the phpErrorHandler is not invoked and, depending on my settings, PHP produces an error message with a stacktrace.

I've tried to add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // do not produce the standard output when an error occurs
error_reporting(-1); // enable error reporting (is this required for Slim?)
```

But any changes that I make in that configuration doesn't seem to affect whether or not my closure is invoked.

**-edit-**

I tried to execute a piece of Javascript that logs to the console. That works for the errorHandler, not for the phpErrorHandler. Also a simple

```
die('oops');
```

doesn't do anything in phpErrorHandler. It appears that the callback isn't invoked at all.

If I put a try/catch around

```
$app->run();
```

I am able to catch errors. However, this causes some nasty side-effects that I prefer to avoid. What that tells me though, is that it's not a config setting that keeps me from catching errors.

Comment: My system setup is PHP 7.1.  I can not reproduce your problem. Throwing `Exception` or `Error` both triggers `phpErrorHandler` handler because both classes implement `Throwable` interface.

Comment: Just curious, can you post your `phpinfo()` output?

Comment: my guess is the `$c['response']` is not the same as the `$response` param the function receives; try with that

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and was slightly led astray by the Slim 3 documentation which mentions the phpErrorHandler feature. However, phpErrorHandler was not added into Slim until version 3.2.0: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/releases/tag/3.2.0

If you are using Slim version < 3.2.0, try upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to disable `display_startup_errors` ?

my config:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

EDIT:
also `die('oops');` is not an error, it will just die/exit execution of script, nothing after that will be executed